Should I use ECS when most of my game's libs are class-based?
I've been studying some external libs for game dev, and I found almost nothing written in an entity-component-system approach. So the question is: should I write my game in ECS or I would lose all the benefits of ECS when my physics, audio, ui and maybe more libs are written using OOP? Would there be any performance difference when using ECS with wrappers around those libs, or it would be simplier and better in terms of performance to use OOP for the whole game?
Here's the implementation overviews of different patterns to use:
ECS: I would hide, for example, RigidBody from some physics engine in a component wrapper or something like this. So it would be RigidBodyComponent. Then, when iterating, special system responsible for physics will invoke common methods of physics engine to update object. My point is that we are losing some of cache-efficiency, which is the most important feature of ECS.
OOP: Simple class wrapper or no wrapper at all. The difference that the whole game would be made from classes, and it would be easier to seamlessly integrate external class-based lib. But again, we are losing in performance. But I want to know how much.

Wrong forum you probably want: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ however the answer is likely benchmark it and see.

"Peformance" is context dependent. Does it matter if your game runs in say 60fps vs 500fps? Of course not. On the other hand if you implement everything by yourself you will never finish any game. The rule of thumb is: if you are not going to simulate tens of thousand of objects, then don't bother with ECS.
